# Changing coordinates of point (from local projected coordinate system to standard coordinate system)?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

How can I convert the coordinates of a point from a projected CRS such as `USER:100001, *Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=30 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=5000000 +ellps=GRS 80 +units=m +no_defs`, which we often use in our country back to WGS84 or UTM?

I use QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

- Load your layer into QGIS,
- right mouse click on the layer name,
- select Save as...
- change the projection to WGS84 in the dialogbox

[image]